# How to create a category page with requested category in homepage in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, category

I need to create a category page with requested category in homepage. Can anyone please help me??
(Note:- category id need to be given from backend.)

Comment: you want like http://magento2demo.firebearstudio.com/gear/fitness-equipment.html  on home page or http://magento2demo.firebearstudio.com/gear.html

Comment: http://magento2demo.firebearstudio.com/gear/fitness-equipment.html is fine for me, but i need to give the category id from backend.(this is for creating an extension.)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a `catalog products list` widget.

In the backend, go to `content > widgets` and click 'Add Widget.' From the type dropdown select 'catalog products list' and select your theme then click continue.

This will take you to the widget configuration page. If you go to the 'Widget Options' section, you can add a condition that specifies the category id.

In the 'Storefront Properties' section, add a layout update and select 'specified page' then select 'CMS Homepage' and 'main content area' container.

This will display the products for the chosen category on the homepage.

Comment: Thanks Arron, for your reply. But I need this for creating an extension.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create cms block
2. Goto the category which you want to click
3. category->display settings
4. Select display mode as static block only
5. Select cms block as already created block in first step